# Trying to get a Codepen button to work but it's being affected by bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, codepen

I'm trying to get a Codepen button to work. After copying and implementing the code the buttons looks totally different than the given examples. It probably is affected by my use of Bootstrap CSS. What is a correct way to find and eliminate the Bootstrap code that is messing up the buttons?

Edit:
Below the code. Sorry for not providing it in the first place. Here is the codepen url with the original code: 
https://codepen.io/soulwire/pen/bKens

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="toggle">
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="button"></span>
<span class="label">+</span>
</div>
<div class="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<span class="button"></span>
<span class="label">–</span>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import compass

/* Squishy buttons */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700)

html, body

font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif
background: url(http://s.cdpn.io/1715/dark_stripes.png)
text-align: center
height: 100%

.container
text-align: center
position: absolute
margin-top: -80px
width: 100%
top: 50%

.toggle
margin: 4px
display: inline-block

.toggle
$size: 140px
box-shadow: inset 0 0 35px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), inset 0 2px 1px 1px      
rgba(255,255,255,0.9), inset 0 -2px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25)
border-radius: 8px
background: #ccd0d4
position: relative
height: $size
width: $size

&:before

$radius: $size * 0.845
$glow: $size * 0.125

box-shadow: 0 0 $glow $glow / 2 #fff
border-radius: $radius
background: #fff
position: absolute
margin-left: ( $radius - $glow ) * -0.5
margin-top: ( $radius - $glow ) * -0.5
opacity: 0.2
content: ''
height: $radius - $glow
width: $radius - $glow
left: 50%
top: 50%

.button

$radius: $size * 0.688

-webkit-filter: blur(1px)
-moz-filter: blur(1px)
filter: blur(1px)

transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000)
box-shadow: 0 15px 25px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 -3px 4px -1px  
rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 -10px 15px -1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6), inset 0 3px 4px      
-1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 0 5px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8), inset 0            
20px 30px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2)
border-radius: $radius
position: absolute
background: #ccd0d4
margin-left: $radius * -0.5
margin-top: $radius * -0.5
display: block
height: $radius
width: $radius
left: 50%
top: 50%

.label
transition: color 300ms ease-out
text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #ccd0d4, 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.8), 1px 1px 4px #fff
line-height: $size - 1
text-align: center
position: absolute
font-weight: 700
font-size: 42px
display: block
opacity: 0.9
height: 100%
width: 100%
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4)

input
opacity: 0
background :red
position: absolute
cursor: pointer
z-index: 1
height: 100%
width: 100%
left: 0
top: 0

&:active
~ .button
box-shadow: 0 15px 25px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4), inset 0 -8px 30px 1px         
rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 -10px 15px -1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6), inset 0 8px   
25px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4), inset 0 0 10px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6)

~ .label
font-size: 40px
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.45)

&:checked
~ .button
box-shadow: 0 15px 25px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4), inset 0 -8px 25px -1px 
rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 0 -10px 15px -1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6), inset 0 8px    
20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 0 5px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6)

 ~ .label
font-size: 40px
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4)
```

Comment: you will need to provide your relevant code other wise no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Try Name spacing the css for the codepen button

Comment: Most likely because the codepen example uses Sass.